# Como ajustar o formato dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c, struct, time

Tenho o seguinte código que pega a data instantânea do computador.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main () {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    printf("Agora: %d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_year+1900);
}
```

Eu preciso guardar a data fornecida em uma variável e eu suponho, pelo enunciado do meu exercício, que ele deve estar no formato dd/mm/yyyy, pois há uma necessidade posterior de pesquisa por meio da data.

Qual seria o método mais fácil de se adicionar as barras? Varrer o vetor com a data e em cada posição ir colocando a barra (foi o que pensei), ou há alguma solução mais eficiente?

Há uma certa dúvida no enunciado quanto a data estar no formato acima, mas não quero correr o risco e tentar por este formato. A pesquisa a qual me referi é o usuário informando duas datas (início e fim) e pesquisar todos os cadastros realizados nesta data.

Qualquer dúvida, perguntem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser apenas guardar em uma variável, pode usar o `sprintf` no lugar do `printf`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main () {
    char minhaString[30];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    sprintf( minhaString, "Agora: %d/%d/%d", tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_year+1900 );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Acho que vai funcionar perfeitamente como eu preciso.